# Far-field analytical solution

Tags: optics, photons, resource-recommendations, diffraction, photonics

I want to compare FDTD far-field solution for reflective diffraction with analytical solution.
It seems more complicated than transmission diffraction.
Please suggest resources or codes for reference.

Comment: What is the difference between reflective diffraction and transmission diffraction? I have never heard of this distinction...

Comment: reflection grating diffracts light back into the plane of incidence while transmission gratings transmit dispersed light through. there's some difference because of reflectivity coeffcients in farfield.

Comment: *that* is "just" diffraction

Comment: so can i use same code for farfield analytical solution?

Comment: could you suggest some good resources to learn about Fraunhofer diffraction farfield analysis using MATLAB/python?

Comment: Sorry but I do not have such code; it is easy to write a "toy code" in matlab for the far field of an aperture that is illuminated by a plane wave and then sum it up for many non-interacting aperture fields with or without reflection or transmission losses. The difficulty is assuming interacting apertures that can be caused by all kinds uncontrolled low-level scatterings at edges, creeping waves, etc., but this is beyond my knowledge. Matlab has an antenna toolbox that includes phased array analysis, maybe you can modify it for gratings.

Comment: i will try that. thank you for your support.

Comment: @hyportnex is there any way to compare electrical field value of  reflective diffraction and transmission diffraction? if both are just diffraction.

Comment: Astronomy grade gratings have been made for more than 150 years or more, those were designed by hand. At what kind of detail you wish to analyze? At the level I know this stuff is a Fourier transform/Fourier series approximation...

Comment: https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1100&context=etd and https://diverdi.colostate.edu/C431/experiments/time%20domain%20fluorescence/diffraction%20gratings/Richardson%20Gratings%20Handbook.pdf

Comment: you may also find this book *very* useful: David Voelz "Computational Fourier Optics : a MATLAB tutorial" SPIE Press,